# how do i make my while loop work?

Tags: python, loops

```
print("sentence analyser")
sentence = input("type in the sentence that you want the program to analyse: ")
keyword = input("type in the word that you want the program to find the position of: ")
sentence = sentence.strip("!£$%^&*()-""_=+[{]}'@#~/?")
sentence = sentence.title()
keyword = keyword.title()
sentence = sentence.split()
while keyword not in sentence:
    keyword = input('word: ')
for (position,words) in enumerate(sentence):
    if (keyword in words): 
         print("the position of your word is",position+1)
```

whenever i type the a word which is in the sentence it works fine, but when i type a word which is not in the sentence it asks me to input another word(as it should) but when i input a word which is in the sentence it just keeps asking me to input a correct word instead of telling me its position in the sentence> thank you hope you can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you do `sentence = sentence.title()` all the words are in Title Case. Then when for the first time you ask for a word you do `keyword = keyword.title()`, so the word is also in Title Case.

But if it doesn't match you only ask for a new word, but *don't* `title()` it so it won't match unless you write it in Title Case yourself.

Fix:

```
while keyword not in sentence:
    keyword = input('word: ').title()
```

Comment: thank you very much, u really helped me here and i feel really stupid for making such an error